# Mathematica: How to insert Matrices into a bigger Sparse Matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sparse-matrix

I created a sparse matrix for a given size n

```
mat = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> U10, Band[{2, 1}] -> V10}, {n*n, n*n}]
For[j = 0, j < n - 1, j++, mat += SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1 + (n*(j + 1))}]->U01, Band[{1 + (n*(j + 1)), 1}] -> V01}, {n*n, n*n}]]
```

now I would like to replace the entries U10,V10,U01 and V01 by some 4x4 matrices such that the original structure is preserved

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

a `SparseArray` can not hold arrays as elements. You need to convert to a normal array, eg.

```
mat=Normal@mat /. {U10->{{1, 2},{3,4}},U01->{{1, 0},{0, 1}},... }
```

If you think to convert that back to a sparse array:

```
SparseArray[mat]
```

you get the error:

> SparseArray::rect: Rectangular array or list of rules expected at position 1

because your array is not rectangular.